Laravel Ably broadcast not working after user login
I'm using ably for broadcasting notifications in my admin panel,
I've followed this repo https://github.com/ably/laravel-broadcaster, to setup ably/laravel-broadcaster and ably larvel echo for the client side
I did ably laravel echo configuration in bootstrap.js as mentioned exactly in the repo
import Echo from '@ably/laravel-echo';
import * as Ably from 'ably';

window.Ably = Ably;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'ably',
    disconnectedRetryTimeout: 500
});
window.Echo.connector.ably.connection.on(stateChange => {
    console.log(stateChange.current);
    // if (stateChange.current === 'connected') {
    //     console.log('connected to ably server');
    // }
});

everything works fine and notification is being broadcasted and received,
but after the user login in my app laravel echo connection failes cuz of a clientId mismatch
Ably: Connection state: failed; reason: [ErrorInfo2: Mismatched clientId for existing connection; statusCode=401; code=40102; see https://help.ably.io/error/40102 ]

if I refreshed the page everything works fine again, it looks like after the client login, ably isn't updating the client id
Note 1: it worth mentioning that I'm using laravel inertia with vue to build my SPA applications
can anyone help? actually I don't know where to start

This was a bug in @ably/laravel-echo, and it was fixed in v1.0.5. Make sure you are using the latest version of the @ably/laravel-echo package.
